# Load MNIST Dataset in Sklearn-Friendly Format

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, mnist

I have loaded the MNIST dataset using the following command:

```
from dataget import data

dataset = data("mnist").get()
```

How do I convert it to Sklearn-friendly format, i.e. features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test?

I have tried "np.loadtxt" but got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: data
```

I have also tried the following lines of code:

```
df = next(dataset.training_set.random_batch_dataframe_generator(10))

df
```

And it has returned this error:

```
AttributeError: training_set
```

Please, can someone help me, I have been googling alternative methods but I still receive errors. Thank you!

P.S. Here's another way I've used to obtain the MNIST dataset:

```
dataset = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

Comment: Hello. Where do you download the data from?

Comment: I've used this line of code to obtain it:

    dataset = data("mnist").get()

I've obtained it from the MNIST database

Comment: In the expression `data("mnist").get()`, you haven't shown how you defined or imported the name `data`.

Comment: I've imported it from the "dataget" library

Comment: Thanks.  You should add the import to the code in the question.

Comment: Could you print out the `dataset` variable?

Comment: @E.Z. This is all I get when printing it: <datasets.mnist.Mnist object at 0x10b7ce550>

However, if I were to use: dataset = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

I'd get this when printing it: {'data': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), 'COL_NAMES': ['label', 'data'], 'DESCR': 'mldata.org dataset: mnist-original', 'target': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  9.,  9.,  9.])}

Comment: Try that: `features_train, labels_train = dataset.data, dataset.target`. Then, print out `features_train` and `labels_train`.

Comment: @E.Z. I got this as an output: [[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]] [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  9.  9.  9.]

I'm assuming now all I need to do is split it into training and test sets yes?

Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Yeah. No problem!

Comment: scikit-learn also has the support for downloading the MNIST data. [See here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#downloading-datasets-from-the-mldata-org-repository)

Answer (score 0):

@E.Z. helped me out with the answer!

```
features, labels = dataset.data, dataset.target
```

I then split them into training and test sets using the following lines of code:

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(features)) < 0.8
mrk = np.random.rand(len(labels)) < 0.8

features_train = features[msk]
features_test = features[~msk]
labels_train = labels[mrk]
labels_test = labels[~mrk]
```